# How do you retrieve the replication factor info in Hdfs files?

Tags: hadoop, replication, hadoop2

I have set the replication factor for my file as follows:

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=5 -copyFromLocal file.txt /user/xxxx
```

When a `NameNode` restarts, it makes sure under-replicated blocks are replicated.
Hence the replication info for the file is stored (possibly in `nameNode`). How can I get that information?

Answer (score 19):

Try to use command `hadoop fs -stat %r /path/to/file`, it should print the replication factor.

Answer (score 15):

You can run following command to get replication factor,

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/xxxx
```

The second column in the output signify replication factor for the file and for the folder it shows `-`, as shown in below pic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Alexey Shestakov's answer, which works perfectly and does exactly what you ask, other ways, mostly found [here](http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/hdfs-user/119xy896e9/get-replication-level-of-a-file-in-hdfs), include:

```
hadoop dfs -ls /parent/path
```

which shows the replication factors of all the `/parent/path` contents on the second column.

Through Java, you can get this information by using:

```
FileStatus.getReplication()
```

You can also see the replication factors of files by using:

```
hadoop fsck /filename -files -blocks -racks
```

Finally, from the web UI of the namenode, I believe that this information is also available (didn't check that).

Answer (score 1):

We can use following commands to check replication of the file.

```
hdfs dfs -ls  /user/cloudera/input.txt
```

or

```
hdfs dfs -stat %r /user/cloudera/input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need to check replication factor of a HDFS **directory**

`hdfs fsck  /tmp/data`

shows the average replication factor of /tm/data/ HDFS folder
[image]