# How to change replication factor while running copyFromLocal command?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm **not asking how to set replication factor** in hadoop for a folder/file. I know following command works flawlessly for existing files & folders.

```
hadoop fs -setrep -R -w 3 <folder-path>
```

I'm asking, how do I set the replication factor, other than default (which is 4 in my scenario), while copying data from local. I'm running following command,

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <src> <dest>
```

When I run above commands, it copies the data from `src` to `dest` path with replication factor as 4. But I want to make replication factor as `1` while copying data but not after copying is complete. Bascially I want something like this,

```
hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 -copyFromLocal <src> <dest>
```

I tried it, but it didn't work. So, can it be done? or I've first copy data with replication factor 4 and then run `setrep` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7630787/2516301) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25166926/2516301) (both asking different questions), this command seems to work:

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=1 -copyFromLocal <src> <dest>
```

The [-D option](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options) means "Use value for given property."

Comment: What does `-D` signify?

Comment: @Abhishek it means "Use value for given property." (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options)